# Ruby Hash: can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, youtube-api

I am new to Ruby, and I am having some problems with hashes.

I have XML returned from the YouTube API that I converted into a hash. Here is the hash returned by Hash.from_xml(): http://pastebin.com/9xxE6iXU

I am trying to grab specific elements from the hash for each result, such as the title, link, author, etc. Whenever I try to loop through the hash or grab a specific element, I receive a "can't convert String into Integer" error.

Here is the code I am using for the loop:

```
@data["feed"]["entry"]["title"].each do  |key, value|
    "<p>"+key+" "+value+"</p>"
end
```

I have also tried grabbing specific elements, such as @data["feed"]["entry"]["title"][0].

How do I loop through the hash and grab specific elements out?

Comment: one question, do you really want to work on a hash here? or did you just try this as the first option; because normally you would you use a xml-parser like nokogiri.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After working with this I have decided to parse the xml first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's happening because `@data["feed"]["entry"]` is array of hashes:

```
puts @data["feed"]["entry"].class  # => Array
```

Each element-hash inside this array has "id", "category", "title" etc. values.

For grabbing each title try to use following snippet:

```
@data["feed"]["entry"].each do |entry|
  puts entry["title"]
end
# => "TABE test adult basic education"
     "WhatCollegesHopeYouWon'tFindOutAboutACTSATTestPrep..."
     ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The code you gave me just outputs the entire hash after "entry" =>

I still am confused as how to grab specific elements from here.

Comment: If you want to take specific element, you can use [], as I show with `title`, isn't it?

Comment: This is what I am getting when I use the above loop: http://pastebin.com/z9WkscFm

Comment: Ok, look at this: I take your code from here http://pastebin.com/9xxE6iXU and make it as @data hash in my example above. After that what I get seems to list of all titles: http://pastebin.com/DYHtP6kM